# Dynamic Select box using javascript multifield in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

Good day,

I've been trying to get all the dynamic select box but it always returning the first color.

For example i have 1 default set of color, but then i click the Add More it adds another set of color but when i posting it in my controller it always return the first color and disregard the other added set of color. This is the sample image [set of color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaPA3.jpg)

Can someone help me on this? I've been stucked for 4days now.

Here's my view code:

```
<div class="form-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p><button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary">Add Color</button></p>
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row group">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label></label>
                <select name="color1[]" id="color1" class="form-control" >
                <option value="" > Color 1</option>

                <?php foreach($colors as $color): ?>
                 <option value="<?php echo $color['colorID']; ?>">
                  <?php echo $color['colorDesc']; ?>
                  </option>
                <?php endforeach; ?> 
              </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label></label>
                <select name="color2[]" id="color2" class="form-control" >
                <option value="" > Color 2</option>

                <?php foreach($colors as $color): ?>
                 <option value="<?php echo $color['colorID']; ?>">
                  <?php echo $color['colorDesc']; ?>
                  </option>
                <?php endforeach; ?> 
              </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btnRemove">X</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".form-content").multifield({
        section: ".group",
        btnAdd:"#btnAdd",
        btnRemove:".btnRemove",
    });
</script>
```

And here's my Controller

```
$color1 = $this->input->post('color1');
$color2 = $this->input->post('color2');

for($i = 0; $i < count($color1); ++$i) {
     echo $make = $color1[$i];

}
```

I just started using Codeigniter newbie in short. Please help me to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you print your post e.g.  echo '<pre>'; print_r($POST); echo '</pre>'; exit; and post here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I not tested):

HTML:

```
<div class="form-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>
                <button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary">Add Color</button>
            </p>
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php $count=0 ; if($this->input->post('color1')) $count = count($this->input->post('color1')); for($i=0;$i<$count,$i++):?>
        <div class="row group">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label></label>
                    <select name="color1[<?php echo $i;?>]" id="color1" class="form-control" <?php set_select( 'color1['.$i. ']',$color[ 'colorID']);?>>
                        <option value=""> Color 1</option>
                        <?php foreach($colors as $color): ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $color['colorID']; ?>">
                            <?php echo $color[ 'colorDesc']; ?>
                        </option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label></label>
                    <select name="color2[<?php echo $i;?>]" id="color2" class="form-control">
                        <option value=""> Color 2</option>
                        <?php foreach($colors as $color): ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $color['colorID']; ?>" <?php set_select( 'color2['.$i. ']',$color[ 'colorID']);?>>
                            <?php echo $color[ 'colorDesc']; ?>
                        </option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btnRemove">X</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endfor;?>
</div>
```

in controller (you can also add validation):

```
...
if($this->input->post('color1')) {
    $result = array();
    $count = count($this->input->post('color1'));
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
        if($this->input->post('color1['.$i.']') && $this->input->post('color2['.$i.']')) {
            $result[$i] = ['color1'=>$this->input->post('color1['.$i.']'),'color2'=>$this->input->post('color2['.$i.']')];
        }
    }
    print_r($result);
}
...
```